# SQLite open and close DB

Tags: android, sqlite

Can below situation (OLD) lead to error `database is locked`?

Old

```
 DataRepository rep0 = new DataRepository (_context);
    InfoRepository rep1 = new InfoRepository (_context);
    rep0.open();
    //do something
    rep1.open();
    //do something
    rep0.close();
    rep1.close();
```

New

```
 DataRepository rep0 = new DataRepository (_context);
    InfoRepository rep1 = new InfoRepository (_context);
    rep0.open();
    rep0.close();
    //do something
    rep1.open();
    //do something     
    rep1.close();
```

I am using SQLiteOpenHelper to open and close the DB.

I tested for both and working, and haven't faced error by myself. As I am tracing a possible error root, because I saw the error log for android app report.

Answer (score 0):

The checker feels that you are opening another connection to an already open database in OLD.

Comment: is it possible to lead error due to OLD code ? I am thinking of changing to NEW one.

Comment: Error may show in OLD when the read/update operations overlap between rep0 and rep1. Change to new but make sure that you don't introduce new accidental bugs. e.g. Don't use any cursors of rep0 when you "// do something" on rep1